# Converted .apk from .jar

Tags: android, sendmessage

I have a Java program which can send messages and it is working when I installed my program as .jar application in my Java application phone, the next day I converted  .jar to .apk (Android), and save it to ipad, but when I am going to open it,it cant send message, is it need for a SIMM card so that the application works? thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: As far as I know the iPad cannot execute an android file. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: I am using iPad that have a Android Platform.. and it is possible to save any .apk format into iPad, but the problem is I cant send messages from iPad..

Comment: @Missy An iPad is a registred trademark of Apple Computer Inc. What you use is an android tablet. There is a tiny but important difference. iPad and tablets with Android belongs to same kind of computers, called tablet pc.

Comment: @Missy: Just to know, how did you converted the `JAR` file to `APK`?

Comment: "mv app.jar app.apk" perhaps? lol

Comment: @Poldie good to know theres a site that ready for conversion here is the site http://www.netmite.com

Comment: there are services out there that allow such conversion - let's assume this is what has been done...

Comment: @reporter thanks sir.. anyway neo is a tablet pc?

Comment: since I already converted it an turned into .apk platform, the problem is, its not working in neo which is supported with Android Apllication..

Comment: @Mudassir good to know theres a site that ready for conversion. :))

Comment: Sadly, though, the site doesn't seem to be able to provide working .APK files, does it.   I mean, if there's no such requirement, you could simply use my mv method and you'll have something functionally identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a message, there exitst only to ways:

1. via simm card to connect to a mobile network provider
2. via wlan, but you need an access point

Comment: @reporter so it is not possible sir to send message with iPad coz it haven't a simm card? then what iPad have an internet connection?

Comment: what kind of messages are you talking about?

Comment: well I've done a program that have 4 textfields 1. field for a number you desire to send, 2. field for a branch code, 3. field for product code and 4. for quantity( amount of product you order) then it works at java application, while in android I dont think so.. :(

Comment: @Missy the simm card contains some login data. This allows the device to use the connection from a public telecommuncation provider. If you loged in, you can use the internet connection for communication. And if you have got an wlan access point, you don't need a simm card.

Comment: @reporter is there any ways in sending message without SIMM card using neo?

Comment: @Missy What is so hard to understand? If you haven't an accsess point for wireless lan you need a simm card!

Answer (score 0):

Java is not supported in iPAD. Probably time for you to buy some Android tablets ;)

Comment: I already converted .jar to .apk(android) for ipad (android Platform) I installed .apk into ipad(android platform), and successfully the application was installed but when I am going to send message from ipad theres no response.. is it possible to send messages with out SIMM card?

Comment: @Missy could you please let me know the device you are using ? Because iPAD doesn't support apk, and for installing any applications in iPad you need go through AppStore or you should have your iPAD jail broken